# Select nth-child in pairs (repeating pattern)?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to build a grid that has `div`s whose `width` follow a specific pattern. In the grid the first 3 divs should have their `width` as `33.333%`, the next 2 should have `width` as `50%`, the next 3 again `width: 33.3333%` followed by next 2 with `width: 50%` and so on (infinite).

The CSS3 `nth-child` seems like a good fit for this, but no matter what I do, it screws up as the numbering because I am having to use `:nth-child` two times. This must be solvable in a smartly CSS manner? Is there a way that I can assign `width` based on this pattern without having to manually set the `width` for each individual `div` one by one?

Comment: please share some code with us

Comment: Sorry but theoretical question would not help you get an answer. Post your code and explain it better. Thanks!

Comment: The question is vaguely worded (possibly because of language barrier) but is definitely not too broad. It seems reasonably clear in what OP is trying to do and the start and end points are defined. I feel this is a case of a good question poorly asked rather than a bad question. Though code showing effort is welcome, it is not mandatory and any additional code provided could possibly lead to XY problems

Comment: Agree with Harry. This is actually a good question. There is no point in Op adding superfluous 3-line code which is explained already in the question.

Comment: I disagree with Harry. Questions about why existing code is not working **must** include that code in the question. Nb: I voted as off-topic for this reason, not as too broad. The question is good aside from missing the critical element of a non-working code snippet.

Comment: The OP here is asking "how" to achieve this and is not asking "why" their code isn't working. I agree that code must be included when the question is a "why" but that is not the case here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Judging by your question, it seems like out of every 5 elements you need the first 3 to have `width` as 33.33% and the next two to have `width` as 50%.

So, you should use the `nth-child` with multiplier as `5n`. The first three elements in every set of five would then be `5n-4`, `5n-3`, `5n-2` whereas the next two would be `5n-1` and `5n`. Using these in the `nth-child` selector like in the below snippet would achieve what you are looking for.

```css
div {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
div:nth-child(5n-4),
div:nth-child(5n-3),
div:nth-child(5n-2) {
  width: 33.33%;
}
div:nth-child(5n-1),
div:nth-child(5n) {
  width: 50%;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

As pointed out by [Abhitalks in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435653/nth-child-in-pairs/33435822#comment54660120_33435822), this could be further simplified by setting one of the `width` as default for all `div` elements and then overriding it. For example, we could set `width: 33.33%` as default for all `div` elements and then override it to `width: 50%` for just `5n` and `5n-1` alone.

```css
div {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 33.33%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
div:nth-child(5n-1),
div:nth-child(5n) {
  width: 50%;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: As a matter of fact, this could be simplified a little by keeping a default width and then using just `5n` and `5n-1` to mark the change --  http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/avL6Lr5s/

Comment: @Abhitalks: Yea, very nice :) I would leave my main answer as it is though because it is more clearer from understanding perspective. Having said that, I would like to add your solution also to the answer. Would you mind?